# Impossible to install the MS Visual Studio... in English

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I got a new PC and try to install Visual Studio. I go to [download visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) page but in any time I can select the English :(

The whole site is in English, but the downloaded installer is in French.

It downloads and installs in French language, is there nothing to to about it?

[image]

**PS.** 
I was able to change the VS GUI in English by "Modifier", then removing the French language pack and adding the English one.

By the "Installer" itself is always in French, any way to make it English...
The same installer is used when updating VS, so now I have an English-like VS and a French "VS updater".

Thanks Microsoft... :(

Comment: Bottom left of the page is the language selector. Also try to re-launch the installer after being installed in French, then pick the "Modify" option. Should display other languages to download and apply.

Comment: the site is in English, but the dowloaded installer is in French

Comment: The installer might be in french, does it install a french version of Visual Studio? If so then make sure you've picked the right language pack in the installer. This can be done on the page where you pick all the components to install, there is a tab along the top for language pack, make sure English is selected there. There is only one installer so it doesn't matter how many times you download it.

Comment: Installs the French Version, because the OS is in French.

Comment: Since you've already installed it, click Modifier and pick the right language pack and accept, this should install English support for you.

Comment: It **defaults** to french.

Comment: But I don't need English support, I need the English Visual Studio. I heard there are less bugs for the "original" VS

Comment: As far as I know, there is just one version of Visual Studio 2017, if you discount all the updates they've released, there's no "English visual studio" vs. "French visual studio", it's just "visual studio with English language pack" and so on.

Comment: When I install it defaults to English language pack, and that should be no different from what you would get if you picked the same.

Comment: because your OS should be English one, the mine is French

Comment: could the downvoter explain WHY? @EzequielLópezPetrucci

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but again, as far as I know, there is just one version of Visual Studio, the one that installer installs. The difference is in which language pack you pick, which is installed as well. If you pick English language pack and install you will get the exact same installation as I do, there is no "French Visual Studio".

Comment: If you heard that the "original Visual Studio" is better than the French you need to go and ask them what they mean by that.

Comment: and why should I reinstall these packages several times, why no possibility to select the language at the first installation? :(
and also any possibility to have the "installer" in English, the same used when updating the product... in French

Comment: The installer itself does not have a language selection. I believe you can pick the language packs when first installing but since I have VS installed I cannot verify this any more. You should only have to install the English language pack once. To be honest, you're probably spending more time here in the comment thread than just checking the "English" language pack and hitting apply and go get a cup of coffee. You don't have any other choice, that's all there is.

Comment: that's the problem. Imagine a English speaking Chinese friend of mine asked to install the English VS on his computer. I will never be able to help him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the first installation of Visual Studio, there are no much choices actually, Microsoft decided to keep the OS Installer language without an alternative.

The Visual Studio default language pack is also the OS language. However could be changed via the respective language pack selection in installer's "Language pack" tab:
[image]

After the first installation, the *installer*'s language can be changed via the following command:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" --locale "en-US"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one version of Visual Studio now and it has different language packs.

In the installer (which will always be in the language of your OS) click your languages equivalent of "more" and then "modify" and in the following dialog select the third tab page that handles language packs. Select the pack you want to use (for example "English").

Comment: VS I hope, is however, a mature product... Incredible I will never be able to install it on a my Chinese friend's machine that is a programming beginner, because of the language of his OS... I will not understand where to click